# CSS Flex align-items

Tags: css, web, flexbox

ho guys i have three icons and i try that two items are on the left side and one on the right side. what sort of flex-properties i need for that?

```css
.flex-container_1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-text: right;
  height: 99%;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-container_1>div {
  margin: 10px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container_1">
  <div id="brilleicon" style=" 
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) url() 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: 70% 70%;
  backgroundColor: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 30px;
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-top: 4%;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  transition: background-color .05s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .05s ease;
  z-index: 9999;"></div>
  <div id="pictureicon" class="clickable" style=" 
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) url() 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: 110% 90%;
  backgroundColor: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 70px;
  min-height: 30px;
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-top: 4%;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  transition: background-color .05s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .05s ease;
  z-index: 9999;"></div>
  <div id="videoicon" class="clickable" style=" 
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) url() 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: 110% 90%;
  backgroundColor: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 70px;
  min-height: 30px;
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-top: 4%;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  transition: background-color .05s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .05s ease;
  z-index: 9999;"></div>
</div>
```

Thats what I have.
It aligned my item from right to left with space between them but i want that the middle icons aligns next to the left item

Comment: can you show your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I wrote a small demo project that you can refer to:

https://codepen.io/sivcan/pen/KeBqGb

The idea is to break the content into two blocks and give it a `justify-content: space-between`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing the following using two object wrappers: (Change row to something else if you are loading Bootstrap or any other CSS framework using a row property)

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="i-left">
      Your flex list for two icons
   </div>
   <div class"i-right">
      Your flex list for one icon
   </div>
 </div>
```

Then using css mark 'row' as a **flex** object itself and then use the relevant properties to make the i-left and i-right class position correctly. You could use **justify-content** to do this and then **align-items** to align them vertically within the row!

This is the most effective way to do things. No need to complicate flex.

*Side Note: Never use that much in-line styling in your html if your indexing this on google. They will cane you for in-line styling like that.*

Comment: @Delidragon No worries, glad you asked here as I see so many websites do flex wrong with no guidance.